# Variable from Android does not recognize in PHP, Spinner

Tags: php, android, spinner

I have a spinner that will fetch some details in the web server and in the where clause it should only fetch
the userID which is from my android. I doubled check if I am passing the right userID but when it comes to my php, it does not recognize the userID that I have passed. And the spinner does not contain any thing.

Moreover, when I substitue the user_id in for example 37 because I have a user_id with that number, there are results in the spinner. I guess it does not recognize my $userID variable. Any help will do. Thanks!

Below is my code

Android

```
String userId = userid.getText().toString();
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", userId));
try
    {   
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urlconnection.getevent); ...
```

PHP

```
 <?php

   $userID=$_REQUEST['user_id'];
     include("config1.php"); 

         $query = "SELECT event_id, event_name,category, budget,date, time, timeend,dateend,user_id
                  FROM event 
                 WHERE user_id = $userID"; 

        $r = mysql_query($query);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($r))

    {
    $cls[]=$row;

    //echo $fin."<br>";

    }

    echo(json_encode($cls));

    mysql_close($con);

    ?>
```

Comment: have you tried to enclose your variable in braces? `{$userID}`

Comment: @kabuto178 
I have tried it already but it does not fetch any thing at all. here's my error in logcat

org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray



but I have tried to set a particular userid for example $userID = 37; and it returns something

Comment: Try to do this `"SELECT event_id, event_name,category, budget,date, time, timeend,dateend,user_id
                  FROM event 
                 WHERE user_id =". $userID;

Comment: Before going any further, try printing the sql statement with the variable somewhere.  This will confirm what you're trying to execute.  Also try printing the $_POST array in the beginning.  Yes, the android processing of results will fail, but you'll be able to see what's happening on the server.

Comment: As aleks G said, that was going to be my next suggestion. Just figured this would have stopped the problem first since it works when he uses an actual number. Maybe the number being passed is not found on the server or its null.

Comment: I have solved the problem. I modified my code to something like this
HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("http://192.168.1.100/EPlanner/fetchEvent.php?user_id=" +userId); and in my php i only modified this $user_id=$_GET["user_id"];

Comment: Anyways, I have tried what you have suggested to print the sql statement. Thanks for your help guys!